# How to get onended event of iframe from asp.net using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, iframe

Hello guys i have a problem with iframe. I want to play video in asp.net and i used iframe.

```
<iframe runat="server"  id="videoPlayer" onended="handlerEnd" style="align-content: center; position:absolute; border:0; top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; width:100%; height:100%" src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I want to use onended event from iframe to use in aspx.cs file. 
How to get it ?

Answer (score 0):

Put a hidden field to your page and set it's value to `0`.

Set event handler to `onended` event, when it fires, set value `1` to hidden field and do postback.

On `Page_Load` event check if hidden field contains `1`.

**Aspx file**

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="videoEndedFlag" />

<iframe onended="raiseVideoEnded" />

function raiseVideoEnded()
{
    var field = document.getElementById('<%=videoEndedFlag.ClientID%>');
    field.value = '1';

    // do postback
    window.location.reload(true);
    // or window.location.href = window.location.href;
    // or __doPostBack('','');
}
```

**Aspx.cs file**

```
protected void Page_Load()
{
    if(IsPostBack)
    {
        if(videoEndedFlag.Value == "1")
        {
            // video ended
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should also set `videoEndedFlag.Value = "0"` somewhere in `Page_Load`, otherwise you video ended code will be triggered for other postbacks as well.